# Windows 10 Stuck at Shutdown does Service: Windows Modules Installer

Tags: windows-10

I have a Windows 10 machine that is stuck saying

"Shutting down service: Windows Modules Installer"

This is on a regular Windows 10 laptop.

The message has been like that for a full hour, With no chance.

I have recently installed VirtualBox on this computer, But it was not running or doing anything when this started happening, I don't know if VirtualBox screwed up the system or not.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks so much!

Comment: Press and hold the power button until it shuts down. Startup and wait 5 min and try shutdown again, is it still hanging at shutdown?

Comment: In an Admin Command prompt, run dism.exe  /online  /cleanup-image  /restorehealth   followed by  SFC /SCANNOW  . When both are complete, restart and test. If these do not work, try uninstalling Virtual Box, restart and test again

Comment: It fixed itself about 100 minutes, Thanks for all the replies and will keep everything in mind if this happens again, Thanks all!